# Selecting multiple nodes using Nokogiri and an upper ancestor node within a variable

Tags: css, ruby, variables, nokogiri, nodes

Last days I was searching for any solution to get multiple nodes using Nokogiri in subject to a reference variable in an ancestor node.

What I need:
Actually I am collecting all "Id"s of "Segment" node. Then I want to collect all subsequent "Resource"s withing the "Segment" node. For collecting the "Resource"s I want to set the "Id" as a variable.

```
<CPL>
  <SegmL>
    <Segment>
        <Id>UUID</Id> #UUID as a variable
        <Name>name_01</Name>
        <SeqL>
            <ImageSequence>
                <Id>UUID</Id>
                <Track>UUID</Track>
                    <ResourceList>
                        <Resource> #depending on SegmentId
                            <A>aaa</A>
                            <B>bbb</B>
                            <C>ccc</C>
                            <D>ddd</D>
                        </Resource>
                    </ResourceList>
            </ImageSequence>
            <AudioSequence>
                <Id>UUID</Id>
                <Track>UUID</Track>
                    <ResourceList>
                        <Resource>
                            <A>aaa</A>
                            <B>bbb</B>
                            <C>ccc</C>
                            <D>ddd</D>
                        </Resource>
                    </ResourceList>
            </AudioSequence>
        </SequL>
    </Segment>
    <Segment>
        <Id>UUIDa</Id>
        <Name>name_02</Name>
        <SequL>
            <ImageSequence>
                <Id>UUID</Id>
                <Track>UUID</Track>
                    <ResourceList>
                        <Resource>
                            <A>aaa</A>
                            <B>bbb</B>
                            <C>ccc</C>
                            <D>ddd</D>
                        </Resource>
                    </ResourceList>
            </ImageSequence>
            <AudioSequence>
                <Id>UUID</Id>
                <Track>UUID</Track>
                    <ResourceList>
                        <Resource>
                            <A>aaa</A>
                            <B>bbb</B>
                            <C>ccc</C>
                            <D>ddd</D>
                        </Resource>
                    </ResourceList>
            </AudioSequence>
        </SequL>
    </Segment>
  </SegmL>
</CPL>
```

All Resource Data each collected with `A = Resource.css("A").text.gsub(/\n/,"")`

```
#first each do
cpls.each_with_index do |(cpl_uuid, mycpl), index|
cpl_filename = mycpl
cpl_file = File.open("#{resource_uri}/#{cpl_filename}")
cpl = Nokogiri::XML( cpl_file ).remove_namespaces!

#get UUID for UUID checks
cpl_uuid = cpl.css("Id").first.text.gsub(/\n/,"")
cpl_root_edit_rate  = cpl.css("EditRate").first.text.gsub(/\s+/, "\/")

  #second each do   
  cpl.css("Segment").each do |s| # loop segment
      cpl_segment_list_uuid = s.css("Id").first.text.gsub(/\n/,"") #uuid of segment list

      #third each do
      cpl.css("Resource").each do |f| #loop resources
          cpl_A = f.css("A").text.gsub(/\n/,"") # uuid of A
          cpl_B = f.css("B").text.gsub(/\n/,"") # uuid of B
      end #third
  end #second
end #first
```

My expression gives me these informations stored in an array:

```
A = 48000.0 
B = 240000.0 
C = 0.0 
D = 240000.0 

Some functions to calculate an average on the resources.

puts all_arry 

A = 5.0
B = 5.0
C = 5.0
D = 5.0
A = 5.0
B = 5.0
C = 5.0
D = 5.0


=8 values -> only 4 values existing for the exact loop (2 average values per Segment)
```

At the moment all "SegmentId"s collecting all "Resource"s

How can I exactly allocate the subsequent resources for eacht Segment Id as a variable?

I had used this code, but the loop is empty, thinking because of some more nodes betwerrn the "Id" of "Segment" and each "Resource" "A", "B"... :

```
if cpl.at("Segment/Id:contains(\"#{cpl_segment_list_uuid}\")")
   cpl.css("Resource").each do |f|
      #collecting resources here for each segmet
   end
end
```

All nodes have NO attribues, ids, class, etc.

May you can help me with my problem. First of all I will politly thank you for your support!

**UPDATE 10/07/16**

I did also run the code with the following expressions for the "each do" on the resources:

```
expression = "/SegmetList/Segment[Id>cpl_segment_list_uuid]"
cpl.xpath(expression).each do |f|
```

It runs the "each do", but I didn't get internal nodes

```
cpl.css("Segment:contains(\"#{cpl_segment_list_uuid}\") > Resource").each do |f|
```

Same as previous

And with a "if"-condition, also the same problem:

```
if cpl.at("Segment/Id:contains(\"#{cpl_segment_list_uuid}\")").each do|f|
#some code
end
```

**UPDATE 2016/18/10**

Actually I get the right number of the resources (4), but still not separated for each Segment. So there are the same four resources in each Segment.

Why I don't get the double number of all resources is, that I create the array in the "Segment"-loop.

This is the present code:

```
#first each do
cpls.each_with_index do |(cpl_uuid, mycpl), index|
cpl_filename = mycpl
cpl_file = File.open("#{resource_uri}/#{cpl_filename}")
cpl = Nokogiri::XML( cpl_file ).remove_namespaces!

#get UUID for UUID checks
cpl_uuid = cpl.css("Id").first.text.gsub(/\n/,"")
cpl_root_edit_rate  = cpl.css("EditRate").first.text.gsub(/\s+/, "\/")

  #second each do   
  cpl.css("Segment").each do |s| # loop segment
      cpl_segment_list_uuid = s.css("Id").first.text.gsub(/\n/,"") #uuid of segment list
      array_for_resource_data = Array.new

      #third each do
      s.css("Resource").each do |f| #loop resources #all resources
      s.search('//A | //B').each do |f| #selecting only resources "A" and "B"
          cpl_A = f.css("A").text.gsub(/\n/,"") # uuid of A
          cpl_B = f.css("B").text.gsub(/\n/,"") # uuid of B
      end #third
  end #second
end #first
```

I hope my update will give you more details. Thank you very much for your help and answer!

**UPDATE 2016/31/10**

The problem with the double output of the segments is fixed. Now I have one more loop on each sequence under the segments:

```
cpl.css("Segment").each do |u|
  segment_list_uuid = u.css("Id").first.text.gsub(/\n/,"")
  sequence_list_uuid_arr = Array.new

    u.xpath("//SequenceList[//*[starts-with(name(),'Sequence')]]").each do |s|
      sequence_list_uuid = s.css("TrackId").first.text#.gsub(/\n/,"") 
      sequence_list_uuid_arr.push(cpl_sequence_list_uuid)

    #following some resource nodes
    s.css("Resource").each do |f|
      asset_uuid = f.css("TrackFileId").text.gsub(/\n/,"") 
      resource_uuid = f.css("Id").text.gsub(/\n/,"") 
      edit_rate = f.css("EditRate").text.gsub(/\s+/, "\/")
      #some more code
    end #resource
  end #sequence list
end #segment
```

Now I want to get all the different "resources" under each unique sequence. I have to list all the different resources and sum up some of the collected values.

Is there any way to collect each resource with different values (sub nodes) under the same "sequence id"? At the moment, I habe no idea for any solution....so there is no code I could show you, that would work in parts.

each_with_index for the "Resource" loop doesn't work.

May you kindly have some ideas or any approach to help me with my new problem?

Comment: See "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Reduce input data and code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that only muddies the question. When updating a question add additional content into the text where you would have put it if it was their initially. Don't use "edited" or "updated" type tags as we can tell what changed. Keeping the question readable and making sense is much more than trying to do some sort of revision marking.

Comment: This question is what we call a "Russian Doll": Please read "[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/153968)"
"[Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188625/153968)"
"[Are questions by default permitted to evolve, and if so, to what extent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310189/128421)"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
resource.search('.//A | .//B')
```

`.//` will anchor the xpath query at the current element rather than searching the whole document.

Example

```
elem = doc.search('ImageSequence').first
elem.search('//A') # returns all A in the whole document
elem.search('.//A') # returns all A inside element
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when tearing apart XML. Write your code similar to how the data is laid out in the XML, allowing for repeating blocks of similar data.

For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

cpl = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<CPL>
  <SegmL>
    <Segment>
        <Id>UUID</Id> #UUID as a variable
        <Name>name_01</Name>
        <SeqL>
            <ImageSequence>
                <Id>UUID</Id>
                <Track>UUID</Track>
                    <ResourceList>
                        <Resource> #depending on SegmentId
                            <A>aaa</A>
                            <B>bbb</B>
                            <C>ccc</C>
                            <D>ddd</D>
                        </Resource>
                    </ResourceList>
            </ImageSequence>
            <AudioSequence>
                <Id>UUID</Id>
                <Track>UUID</Track>
                    <ResourceList>
                        <Resource>
                            <A>aaa</A>
                            <B>bbb</B>
                            <C>ccc</C>
                            <D>ddd</D>
                        </Resource>
                    </ResourceList>
            </AudioSequence>
        </SequL>
    </Segment>
  </SegmL>
</CPL>
EOT
```

Start by finding the node that contains the data you want to iterate over, then start descending into that data:

```
data = cpl.search('Segment').each_with_object([]) { |segment, ary|
    hash = {}

    hash[:id] = segment.at('Id').text
    hash[:name] = segment.at('Name').text

    image_sequence = segment.at('ImageSequence')
    image_sequence_h = {}
    image_sequence_h[:id] = image_sequence.at('Id').text
    image_sequence_h[:track] = image_sequence.at('Track').text

    image_resources_h = {
        a: image_sequence.at('A').text,
        b: image_sequence.at('B').text,
        c: image_sequence.at('C').text,
        d: image_sequence.at('D').text,
    }

    audio_sequence = segment.at('AudioSequence')
    audio_sequence_h = {}
    audio_sequence_h[:id] = audio_sequence.at('Id').text
    audio_sequence_h[:track] = audio_sequence.at('Track').text

    audio_resources_h = {
        a: audio_sequence.at('A').text,
        b: audio_sequence.at('B').text,
        c: audio_sequence.at('C').text,
        d: audio_sequence.at('D').text,
    }

    image_sequence_h[:resources] = image_resources_h
    audio_sequence_h[:resources] = audio_resources_h

    hash[:image_sequence] = image_sequence_h
    hash[:audio_sequence] = audio_sequence_h

    ary << hash
}
```

This is more verbose than I'd usually write it because I wanted the steps to be clearer.

The end result is an array of hashes:

```
# => [{:id=>"UUID",
#      :name=>"name_01",
#      :image_sequence=>
#       {:id=>"UUID",
#        :track=>"UUID",
#        :resources=>{:a=>"aaa", :b=>"bbb", :c=>"ccc", :d=>"ddd"}},
#      :audio_sequence=>
#       {:id=>"UUID",
#        :track=>"UUID",
#        :resources=>{:a=>"aaa", :b=>"bbb", :c=>"ccc", :d=>"ddd"}}}]
```

Then it's easy to iterate over the array and access individual chunks of data, or individual elements of the data:

```
data[0][:image_sequence][:id] # => "UUID"
data[0][:audio_sequence][:resources][:d] # => "ddd"
```